# Is there a way to put an image into the legend of a bar chart (chart.js)?

Tags: chart.js

A simple stacked bar graph

```
<head>
    <title>Stacked Bar Chart</title>
    <script src="Chart.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="utils.js"></script>
    <style>
    canvas {
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div style="width: 75%">
        <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    </div>
    <button id="randomizeData">Randomize Data</button>
    <script>
     chartColors = {
      redborder: 'rgba(206, 0, 23, 1)',
      darkredborder: 'rgba(206, 0, 23, 0.75)',
      lightredborder: 'rgba(206, 0, 23, 0.5)',
             };
        var barChartData = {
            labels: [1<img src='images/badges/Manchester United.png' alt='Manchester United.png' height='30' width='30'>,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32],
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Goals',
                backgroundColor: window.chartColors.redborder,
                data: [0,1,3,0,2,0,0,2,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,2,1,0,1,2,1,1,0,0,0,2,2,0,3]
            }, {
                label: 'Assists',
                backgroundColor: window.chartColors.darkredborder,
                data: [0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1]
            }, {
                label: 'Indirect',
                backgroundColor: window.chartColors.lightredborder,
                data: [0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,2,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1]
            }]

        };
        window.onload = function() {
            var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
            window.myBar = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: barChartData,
                options: {
                    title: {
                        display: true,
                        text: 'Chart.js Bar Chart - Stacked'
                    },
                    tooltips: {
                        mode: 'index',
                        intersect: false
                    },
                    responsive: true,
                    scales: {
                        xAxes: [{
                            stacked: true,
                        }],
                        yAxes: [{
                            stacked: true
                        }]
                    }
                }
            });
        };

        document.getElementById('randomizeData').addEventListener('click', function() {
            barChartData.datasets.forEach(function(dataset) {
                dataset.data = dataset.data.map(function() {
                    return randomScalingFactor();
                });
            });
            window.myBar.update();
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

in the x-axis labels, I am trying to get a small icon (image) to be displayed instead of a number. I have tried to put just the image tag in all possible combinations of `"` and `'` as well as with the number. But to no avail. The chart does not render. It seems that the label needs to recognized as a value to render and the html tag knocks this out of place. I don't see why an image tag cannot be put in there, is there a way to do this?

Comment: It's not clear if you need to customize legend labels or tooltip labels. In fact in your example, labels array is referred to x-axis categories, label field in each dataset is used for legend (3 items), and values from dataset.date are shown on tooltips

Comment: It's for the x-axis.

Comment: You can only customize legends using HTML elements, ticks on x/y axis can only customized with text using custom ticks format (see http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/labelling.html).